# Calling a Listener and location.reload() Method within the mounted Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ethereum, metamask

I have tried to include a listener (`window.ethereum.on`) for an event in my `mounted () {}` method. When the listener is triggered, it itself triggers the `location.reload()` method.

When including this listener and `location.reload()` method in my `mounted () {}` method, it is triggered in an infinite loop, the `location.reload()` method being re-triggered at every reload. However, if I include the listener outside the mounted method, it is never called. Where should the listener be defined?

```
 mounted () {
   ...
   window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
     ...
     window.location.reload(true)
   })
 }
```

Comment: you won't get much help without code, details of the event, what triggers the event etc

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda. I could always add some code, but there is actually nothing exceptional about it. I was thinking that perhaps the listener or location.reload() method needs to be inserted elsewhere in the code, instead of within the mounted() method. I do not think that there is an issue with the code itself, but rather the location where it is defined.

Comment: I have added a simplified extract of my code, for simplicity. The code not included does not have any impact on the issue encountered.